# getting error in understanding friend function in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Why am I am getting an "expected identifier" error before `.token`?

Please provide a solution to understand `friend` function properly.

At first, I am getting a forward declaration error, but I resolved that one by myself.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class a;

class b
{
public:
    void search(a and);
};

class a
{
    string name;
    friend void b::search(a and);
public:
};

void b::search(a and)
{
    cout << and.name;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: `and` is a reserved word in C++ (as alternative spelling of `&&`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For compatibility with old keyboards and encoding schemes where some symbols weren't available, [certain keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) can be used in place of symbols. Among them, `and` is a valid replacement for `&&`. So your `and.name` is actually getting parsed as `&&.name`, which is a syntax error.

The (unfortunate) solution to your problem is: Don't name variables `and` or any of the other words on that list.

Comment: Why do you call the solution "unfortunate"? Don't you agree that variables should have descriptive and meaningful names anyway?